# SSRS report: Preview OK, Deployment OK, but looks in wrong server after release

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportmanager

I've a set of reports in a Visual Studio/SSRS project. We've recently moved the store procedures for the reports to a different server.

The shared data source has been pointed to the new server & db.

A particular report previews ok within Visual Studio, deploys with no errors but when running in Live environment it gives an error "Invalid object name 'CARE.dbo.contact_suppressions'. This is from some embedded sql in report which is fine when previewed & deployed though beforehand so when run in correct environment it works.

It seems to be looking at old server & db still after deployment. If I replace with old server db name in the embedded sql it works but shouldn't be going anywhere near there as the data source points to new server.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the report using a chared datasource on the report server? If so, have you updated the **deployed** datasource? By default, datasources aren't redeployed with a project if they already exist on the instance.

Comment: There's a shared data source within the visual studio project that all its reports refer to if that's what you mean?

Comment: I've set overwrite datasources to True in project report definition. How else would I update deployed data source ?

Comment: Navigate to the SSRS portal (by default http://YourServerName/Reports ). Then open the Data sources Folder. Find the respective Datasource in there, and you'll be able to update it's connection string/settings.

Comment: Bear with me as I catchup with terminology please. We have a web portal with hierachy of folders & their reports to run in Live. Don't see a data sources folder though just the report in question.  There's also the actual folder structure on server and within project folder is an rds file for the data source

Comment: Datasources, by default, is in the root folder. If not, then the location isn't the default, so you'll need to navigate to what you changed it to.,

Comment: Switch the view to list view, it may be a hidden folder but hidden folders will show in list view.

Comment: Yes there was a hidden folder. Thank you very much